# Dask groupby transform

Tags: dask

I am trying to compute the frequency of a grouping defined by multiple columns and I want that frequency output to the original dask dataframe.

For instance.  I want this table

```
ID      PayMethod  Day
```

```
45      CC         Monday    
45      Cash       Monday   
45      CC         Tuesday   
57      Cash       Tuesday
57      Cash       Tuesday
69      CC         Saturday 
69      Cash       Sunday
```

To look like this:

```
ID      PayMethod  Day      ID_PayMethod_Count ID_PayMethod_Day_Count
```

```
45      CC         Monday    2                 1
45      Cash       Monday    2                 1
45      CC         Tuesday   2                 1
57      Cash       Tuesday   2                 2
57      Cash       Tuesday   2                 2
69      CC         Saturday  1                 1
69      Cash       Sunday    1                 1
```

Groupby + transform gives us a groupby object that gives us the same number of rows as the original dataframe.

In pandas I could do the following

```
df['ID_PayMethod_Count'] = df.groupby(['ID','PayMethod','Count']).transform(np.size)
```

Currently Dask does not implement the groupby transform method.  I was wondering if there was an alternative, whether it be some vectorized operation that could be applied to get to the same place or some other way.  I know this could be done with a groupby/aggregation/merge operation but I'm trying to avoid this as it results in a memory issues and the operation not completing (these are large files).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent computation can be achieved with a combination of methods. Here is an example for the ID_PayMethod column (I note there is no Count in your provided data)

```
txt = """ID      PayMethod  Day
45      CC         Monday
45      Cash       Monday
45      CC         Tuesday
57      Cash       Tuesday
57      Cash       Tuesday
69      CC         Saturday
69      Cash       Sunday"""

# set up data
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(b), delim_whitespace=True)
d = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# return aggregate as a concrete pandas dataframe
counts = d.groupby(['ID', 'PayMethod']).count().compute()

# compute look of output, or supply directly if you know
meta = df.assign(ID_PayMethod=df.apply(
    lambda x: counts.loc[(x['ID'], x['PayMethod'])], axis=1))[:0]
# apply the "apply" to each chunk, using the computed counts
d.map_partitions(lambda ddd: ddd.assign(ID_PayMethod=ddd.apply(
    lambda x: counts.loc[(x['ID'], x['PayMethod'])], axis=1)), meta=meta)
```

Doing a `.compute()` on this final output produces the following

```
   ID PayMethod       Day  ID_PayMethod
0  45        CC    Monday             2
1  45      Cash    Monday             1
2  45        CC   Tuesday             2
3  57      Cash   Tuesday             2
4  57      Cash   Tuesday             2
5  69        CC  Saturday             1
6  69      Cash    Sunday             1
```